# Deploying in GAE using Google cloud SDK shell

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, hosting

I am trying to deploy my Nodejs application on Google App Engine. I am using Google Cloud SDK Shell for running the gcloud commands.

First I ran gcloud init:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud init
```

After which I selected the cloud-project to use.
Then I went to my project directory and ran the deploy command:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Hosting\api>gcloud app deploy
```

But when I ran **gcloud app browse**, I am getting **502 Bad Gateway**.
My project structure is :

```
->api
  |___node_modules
  |___models
  |___routes
  |___index.js
  |___app.yaml
  |___package.json
  |___package.lock.json
->public
  |___index.html
  |___js
```

1. Where should I run the **gcloud app deploy** command?
2. Should I change the project structure (How will google-sdk know my frontend files are in /public folder when I am running the command from /api)

**Note**: I am already running on port 8080 and have included "start" script in package.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-structure my project:

```
->project
  |___node_modules
  |___models
  |___routes
  |___index.js
  |___app.yaml
  |___package.json
  |___package.lock.json
  |___public
      |___index.html
      |___js
```

This is my app.yaml file

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
threadsafe: true
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

# Handle the main page by serving the index page.
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*)

# Recommended file skipping declaration from the GAE tutorials
skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yml
  - ^(.*/)?#.*#
  - ^(.*/)?.*~
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
  - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
  - ^(.*/)?\..*
  - ^(.*/)?tests$
  - ^(.*/)?test$
  - ^test/(.*/)?
  - ^COPYING.LESSER
  - ^README\..*
  - \.gitignore
  - ^\.git/.*
  - \.*\.lint$
  - ^fabfile\.py
  - ^testrunner\.py
  - ^grunt\.js
  - ^node_modules/(.*/)?
```

Also, I had to make some changes in the index.js file.
Previously:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, "localhost",()=>{
    console.log("Server running at port " + port);
});
```

I had to replace it with:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("Server running at port " + port);
});
```